# SSO link not working in Edge browser in a SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-edge

There is a hyperlink in our SharePoint 2013 site, which takes to an external site through SSO.
This hyperlink is working fine in Chrome and IE browsers while in Edge it is throwing the below error:

"The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.
If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403(Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410(Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address".

Any help on this is highly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? Please try the hyperlink in Edge InPrivate mode to see if the issue still exists. Does the link work well if it doesn't in the SharePoint site? The error usually means the directory names are wrong, please check if you're using the right path. It's hard to tell with only the above information.

Comment: @Yu Zhou:  Thanks for your response!!!
Yes, when I accessed the site in Edge InPrivate mode, the hyperlink is working fine. It even works fine when I right click on it and select 'Copy Shortcut' and paste it in search bar and hit enter.
Can you please let me know what went wrong while accessing the same site in normal edge browser? Please let me know if some more info is needed
Am using Edge version: 88.0.705.56

Comment: If it works in InPrivate mode, I think it may be related with your SharePoint site cache and cookies. InPrivate mode won't save your browsing history, cookies and site data, or information entered in forms which means the browser is "clean". I suggest that you can clear all the cached things like cookies, storage, passwords and so on which related with your SharePoint site in Edge and try again.

Comment: This is resolved by modifying Edge browser settings. The site was previously running in IE mode in edge browser, now it is running in native edge mode which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by modifying Edge browser settings. The site was previously running in IE mode in edge browser, now it is running in native edge mode which resolved the issue.